# AWS Amplify using VS 2022

Tags: node.js, reactjs, amazon-web-services, visual-studio-2022

I'm new to React/AWS and have recently developed an application using VS Code, which seems to be the go-to tool. I'm wondering if it's possible to use VS 2022, which is a more feature rich dev environment?

I can create a Node.js app with React in VS 2022, but looking at the publishing options there is no option to publish to Amplify, only Elastic Beanstalk which I don't want to use.

Can you publish the app using the Amplify CLI if it's been written with VS 2022?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VS Code is a simple text editor and VS Visual Studio is a full IDE, it has more features but for most cases (especially while learning) the extra features aren't necessary so a lot use VS Code both have addons you can integrate to customise to your liking.

The amplify in the CLI will work for both VS 2022 and VS Code, just be sure the file-path is the correct one.

Regarding publishing to Amplify, you can publish to github and on your aws amplify account you will pull from github to publish it.

keep in mind how you initially created your react application (i.e. create-react-app or create vite)
As these different methods create different file paths.
an example of publishing a vite react app, they use amplify cli to prepare a yaml file (build settings) specifically for vite
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Rvl4nua2IJw

another uses create-react-app
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XD6eJalN1Tw

and both upload to github and pull from there, so everytime you push to github your website will automatically update on amplify.

hope any of this helps and gives you a direction!